# How can I make a simple, login, register page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I've searched ..a lot and I Found so many examples..but complicated and different..

Would someone please show me some tutorials how can I make a simple register , login page.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) should meet your requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.Net MVC, I would highly recommend you go through the [MVC Music Store](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store) tutorial.  It covers the important aspects of the technology, including Membership and Authorization.